# AzureSearch- Error on detecting index schema from data source

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I created a data source on Azure Search via rest API. I use the API instead of portal, as I have a rowversion data type that isnt handled yet on portal. I am  able to view the data source on portal

When I try to import the data source into an index, I get the following error

"Error detecting index schema from data source: "Data source payload should specify at least one of datasouce name and type"

What am I missing here?

Comment: We are investigating. BTW, portal now supports rowversions for change tracking, so you can try creating the whole thing from scratch in the portal.

Comment: @EugeneShvets-MSFT: I do see rowversion on the portal. Thanks. Is there a way I can see & edit synonym maps via portal (or does it have to be via API)

Comment: Synonym maps are not supported in the portal yet. Only the API for now.

Comment: I am having the same problem today. No idea how to solve. Stuck in the first stage itself. Not a very good sign to boost my confidence in using MS Azure Search :( !

Comment: i also facing same issue, when trying to connect with cosmos db, its working find with sql database.