# Where can I find what "Fields" are in my Azure Storage Blob Container for use with Azure Search Index?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I can't seem to find this information in any MSFT documentation. I'm wanting to create a new search index from an already existing Storage Blob Container, but can't seem to do so by clicking on the "Add Search" button from the storage view. So, I decided to go the other way and create the index by linking to the blob storage, but selecting "Import Data >  existing blob" gives another error when trying to validate the data:

Error detecting index schema from data source: ""

Searching on that error led me to this: 
[AzureSearch- Error on detecting index schema from data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762131/azuresearch-error-on-detecting-index-schema-from-data-source)

which was not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to hear that the Azure Portal is not working when you try to import a Blob container into Azure Search. Is it possible to try the [Create Indexer REST Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer) or the [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/search?view=azure-dotnet)? There's a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/DotNetHowToIndexers) on how to use the SDK to create indexers. There's also a [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#setting-up-blob-indexing) you can follow which walks you through all the steps the portal takes when it runs the import data step.

Comment: Thanks, I am going through those now, but my initial issue is that I don't know which fields are accessible from my blob container. I'm uploading outlook.msg files if it helps.

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#content-type-specific-metadata-properties

Outlook message files have the following metadata fields. These are Edm.String in the index:
metadata_content_type, metadata_message_from, metadata_message_to, metadata_message_cc, metadata_message_bcc, metadata_creation_date,, metadata_last_modified, metadata_subject

Other blob metadata fields:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#how-azure-search-indexes-blobs